# Embed youtube videos using the HTML5 player

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I noticed that embedded videos are still using the old flash player.

**Would it be possible to change the embedded video settings to use the HTML5 player?**

I've seen other sites that embed youtube videos use the HTML5 player so we should be able to do the same too.

Comment: Other SE sites? or do you mean other sites in general?

Comment: Would this be better off on the ubermeta? Probably get more eyeballs over there at least

Comment: @JonK: I thought about it. I didn't know how many other sites supported Youtube embedding. As far as I know, it's only used here. I saw [another request](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3797/use-widescreen-for-embedded-youtube-videos) regarding the embedded video size [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93184/use-widescreen-format-for-embedded-youtube-links). I wasn't sure what was best.

Comment: Good news! We're looking into converting our youtube embeds to [use iframes instead of embedded flash objects](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). Iframes should load the HTML 5 player on supported browsers. It's obviously a little early to say whether we'll run into any blocking issues, but I'll make sure to update this question either way. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: Cool, hopefully you'll have even better news coming our way soon of it being implemented and live. :)  I don't think there should be too many issues here, if any.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All Stack Exchange sites that have either YouTube or SoundCloud embedding enabled now use the respective IFRAME embeds. In light of [recent](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2015/07/13/two-more-critical-flash-flaws-discovered-in-hacking-team-data-breach/) flash-related [happenings](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/blocked/p946), we have also re-rendered all affected posts, which means that even old questions and answers that contain an embedded video will now use the HTML5 player.

Bye bye, Flash.

[image]

Comment: Yay! End of an era. :)

Comment: How long did it take, compared to the amount of time spent making the gif? :-P

Comment: @fredley The gif is just a screen recording from http://stackexchange.github.io/stackegg/, that didn't take long :)

Comment: @balpha Ah, I completely missed StackEgg, so didn't recognize it!

Comment: Hey balpha, maybe I'm going crazy but it looks like it has reverted back to the old flash players. I was certain it was on the HTML5 player before. I only noticed now when I attempted to uninstall flash. Had to reinstall again. Did something change? [Here's a screenshot in FF](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5mogA.jpg)

Comment: Hmm, actually it seems like it only happens on some questions? [This one is the one shown in the screenshot that uses flash](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228484), [and this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228008). [This one doesn't](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228427).

Comment: @JeffMercado I'm not seeing flash in http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/228022/334, but I do (well, did; I've fixed that one) in http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/228517/334. Note that the ultimate decision whether to serve flash or the HTML5 player is in YouTube's hand, we just include the iframe. The one from your screenshot is broken because it was created via the API (using the iOS app), and I forgot to deploy the API with these changes. I'll fix that up, thanks.

Comment: I just realized my last comment made no sense, heh. But looks good to me. I think those are the only two variations of youtube urls. Thanks for getting that updated.